# Ubuntu 12.04 in Win 8.1 Hyper-V VM won't reach internet

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, windows-8, hyper-v

I have a Surface Pro 2. I was able to successfully create a virtual machine on Hyper-V and install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit in it. That was fine. However, I can't an internet connection through Ubuntu. Of course, the wireless connection works perfectly on Windows 8.1 on the Surface Pro.

I have already created an external virtual switch on Hyper-V Manager that is 'bound' to the Marvell Avastar 350N Wireless Network Controller of the Surface Pro 2. After that I added that virtual switch to the virtual machine that has Ubuntu. However when I start Ubuntu on the virtual machine, it can't connect to the internet.

NOTE: when I create the virtual switch on Hyper-V manager and I go to "Network and Sharing Center" I can see the virtual switch but it says "No Internet Access". Now I have no idea how to fix this.

I would appreciate any help since I need to run Ubuntu for my Programming 3 class.

`cat /etc/network/interfaces` shows:

```
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: @K7AAY hopefully that helps man. Thanks!

Comment: @K7AAY added what came up in the question. Not sure if it was supposed to work but it doesn't. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. The fix is fairly simple, create an internal switch, then set you *wifi* adapter to share its connection with the newly created internal network. You should be golden.

Comment: Can you explain *how* to do that?

Comment: @pretakor how do i make the wifi adapter share the connection with the internal switch?